# perl different time format output

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert to some date format from the below hash output.  I am in need of convert many hash output to this date format below. I am using this below code now. it seems this code is not proper way I used.

Please share your thoughts to get that time format as simple way from the each hash output

```
my $status_update_time = "$row->{'update_time'}";
$status_update_time =~ m/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\ (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;
my ($year, $month, $date,$hours,$minute,$second) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
my $date_time = "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6TZ"; #2015-08-11T04:31:41Z# expecting this time output

my $next_check = "$row->{'next_check'}";
$next_check =~ m/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\ (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;
my ($year, $month, $date,$hours,$minute,$second) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
my $next_check_time = "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z"; #2015-08-11T04:31:41Z# expecting this time output
```

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using Time modules available on CPAN?

Comment: I can use the module to convert. however, I need to change the resulted date format again like my $date_time = "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6Z";(2015-08-11T21:17:41Z), so I am trying to manage code in simple lines instead of multiple lines like above code posted. since I need to convert this format to many individual hash output . thanks

Comment: You could use `DateTime::Format::ISO8601` for that.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Trying to put too much stuff into a "simple line" will likely result in code that is very hard to read. Instead you should organize it in a `sub` and use clear names for your variables. It's better to have a few more lines of code, but concise and easy to understand blocks of those. Add some comments explaining why you need to do that conversion between formats back and forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece). It's a standard part of the Perl distribution. Use `strptime` (string parse time) to parse your string into a Time::Piece object. Then use `strftime` (string format time) to display your Time::Piece object in whatever format you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $in_format  = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
my $out_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ';

my $in_date = '2015-08-18 08:51:00';

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($in_date, $in_format);

say $date->strftime($out_format);
```

Comment: hi , now able to convert this format , however, I would like to assign the output time format to some varabile , if I assign the output , I am not getting , please let me know how to fix this

say format_custom_to_iso($row->{update_time});
say format_custom_to_iso($row->{next_check});

2015-05-11T21:17:41Z
2015-05-12T09:17:41Z

like  
$old_time = say format_custom_to_iso($row->{update_time});
$new_time = say format_custom_to_iso($row->{next_check});

Comment: Putting code into a StackOverflow comment is a really bad idea. If you have a new question then please ask a new question.

Comment: `$new_time = say format_custom_to_iso($row->{next_check}` makes no sense at all. You're storing the return value from `say` (which will just be a true or false value). If you want to display the result and copy the value in the same line then use `say $new_time = format_custom_to_iso($row->{next_check}` instead. But this is pretty basic programming.

Comment: hi, thank you so much. I didn;t use that 'say' before. sorry for that.  Now I am able to get it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamps are already almost in the right format. There are only two or maybe three things that are not.

- Your regex has a `$` in the end but not a `^` in the beginning, so maybe the timestamp fields are starting with garbage. If yes, that needs to be removed. If not, ignore this point.
- The space should be a `T`
- There should be a `Z` in the end

You are also repeating the same pattern twice. That is an indication that you really want a subroutine so you only need to write the code once.

Then you are assigning a bunch of variables (`$year`, `$month`, ...) that you are never using. That's very inefficient if this is in a loop with lots of iterations. There would also be a warning saying you redeclared all of those, because you declare them again with `my` a few lines down. `use warnings` would tell you about that.

Especially if this is run a lot of times, rolling your own for this simple substitution is faster than using a full-featured parser.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $row = {
  update_time => 'foo 2015-05-11 21:17:41',
  next_check => '2015-05-12 09:17:41',
};

say format_custom_to_iso($row->{update_time});
say format_custom_to_iso($row->{next_check});

sub format_custom_to_iso {
  my ($timestamp) = @_;

  # remove non-digits from the front (maybe this can be omitted)
  $timestamp =~ s/^[^0-9]+//;

  # replace the space with a T in the middle
  $timestamp =~ tr/ /T/;

  # and add a Z in the end
  return  $timestamp . 'Z';
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-05-11T21:17:41Z
2015-05-12T09:17:41Z
```